# Finding files with name with 1 to infinite occurrences of a char

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gnu

I have an exercise which asks how can I use *find* to browse for files which name starts with a case-insensitive, followed by a certain amount of letters or numbers and ends with a number between 3 and 6.
I suppose it's something like this `find . -name '[aA]*[3-6]'`, but the `*` allows all chars rather than only letters or numbers.
And if I put `find . -name '[aA][a-z,A-Z,0-9][3-6]'` it will only show one occurrence.

How can i get multiple undefined occurrences of just letters or numbers?

Comment: Try `find . -iregex '.*/a[a-z0-9]*[3-6]'`

Comment: Please note that none of the tags applied to this question are relevant.  `find` is part of [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/), not bash, linux, or unix.  Notably, POSIX `find` doesn't support the `iregex` option, so answers may not work for Unixes which ship with non-GNU utilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
find . -iregex '.*/a[a-z0-9]*[3-6]'
```

Note that `iregex` will make the pattern case insensitive.

The pattern matches:

- `.*/` - any 0+ chars up to the last `/`
- `a` - `a` or `A`
- `[a-z0-9]*` - 0 or more letters or digits
- `[3-6]` - `3`, `4`, `5` or `6`.

The pattern here requires a full string match.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining!